# Predicting population mean and variance based on sample mean and variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference

I have measurements of lengths of 25 parts which has specification of length±tolerance, what methods can be used predict population mean and variance ?
Example:

length values : (7.5,7.5,9,8.5,10,8,8,8,8,8,7.5,7,8,8,7.5,8,8.5,8,8,8,8.5,8.5,8.5,8)

Specification : 8 ± 2

When I carry out one sample t-test in R  I get following results :

t = 0.86584, df = 23, p-value = 0.3955

alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 8

95 percent confidence interval:

7.855292 8.353042

sample estimates:

mean of x 
= 8.104167

Comment: You can't predict a population mean. You can only use samples to understand where the population mean might be. Larger your samples, greater the likelihood of being close to population mean.

Comment: So there is no method to accept or reject the lot based on above data?

Comment: Your acceptance or rejection is based on a known value. In your case it seems to be 8. So the one sample t-test simply verifies if the sample's mean is within reasonable bounds from the expected mean of 8.

Comment: and variance can be checked using single sample F-test , right?

Comment: Yes, but it usually involves comparing two samples. Not sure about using an f-test on a single sample.

Comment: Siddhesh, I fear that this comment trail might be going in a misleading direction.  Could you clarify your objectives?  Is it possible that you are trying to test whether the population mean lies within the interval $8\pm 2=[6,10]$?

Comment: @whuber: yes, Exactly.

Comment: OK: since there are two endpoints to this interval, exactly what t-test did you run?

Comment: I used this code t.test(y, mu = 8), where y is the data

Comment: Now I think it doesn't make any sense:(